# Angular 13 Hightchart not loading in different tabs

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-ui-router, highcharts-ng, ngzone

when page loaded(Home page), the highcharts are loading correctly. After changing tabs or  components and then  pressing back to the  previous tab or component(Home page) , the highcharts doesn't loading

here i am using angular 13 ,highcharts, bootstrap 5

here is the link of stackblitz i have used
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular13-highcharts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflow on chart to reload the view, more examples of uses you find on [Highcharts angular wrapper](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular).

```
  reflowChart(): void {
    this.chartRef.reflow();
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-mnq8h7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)